# how to restart mysql service from mysql docker container

Tags: mysql, bash, docker

I'm using tommylau/mysql docker image which provides mysql installed.

But after all i can't find how to restart mysql service inside running container (there is no mysql service or /etc/init.d/mysqld)

Any idea how to find how to restart mysql?

Comment: You could just restart the entire container?

Comment: I imagine stopping/restarting the process will kill the container

Comment: Per https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/docker-mysql-more-topics.html, `mysqld` is at `/usr/sbin/mysqld`.

Answer (score 30):

If you log into the container and attempt to restart the service it will essentially kill the container at the point in which the mysql process stops and therefore it'll never start (as the container has exited).

The best way is to simply restart the container using the following command:

```
docker restart [ContainerID]
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked for a docker/mysql  setup in an old Ubuntu  14.x box

Comment: This is not the answer to the question. You can restart the Docker container as any other Docker container, but that does not answer the original question.

Comment: @foki Having looked at it further, the official mysql image does not provide the ability to restart the MySQL process from within the container. The answer I have provided is the closest answer to the question I could provide. I could have provided the less helpful answer of "You can't" but this wouldn't be in the spirit of the SO community.

Comment: @mtt_g Fair enough.

Comment: by far the easiest solution

Answer (score -12):

An easy was going into your container

```
docker exec -it [containername/id] bin/bash
```

after entering the container restart mysql

```
restart mysql
```

or just restart your container like in the answer above

Comment: This is dependent on the type of image used and the service management utilities therein. It would also depend on how the restart process is managed, if it happens to stop PID 1 in the process then the container will stop and will need to manually started (unless --restart always has been used when running the container initially).

Comment: here should be: ```service mysql restart```